# mysql search string and numbers like #654

Tags: mysql

I have a quick question how can I search #some number in mysql> For example

```
Select * from table where field contains #numbers?
```

where #numbers represent any number(example: #123, #345, ...) which has more then four characters. How should I do it correctly?

EDIT: I get what I need with this

```
Select * from table where field REGEXP '^#+[0-9]'
```

Is that ok? And I also need to be at least three characters long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the numbers to be at least 3 digits long, try:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE field  RLIKE '#[0-9]{3,}'
```

Comment: It will also select strings with more than 3 numbers.

Comment: @Mihai The OP's edit states *"And I also need to be at least three characters long"*...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE fields REGEXP '^#[0-9]{3}'
```

If i understand you..

Answer (score 0):

If I have good understood you that code should solve your problem : `SELCET * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%#%s'`

Comment: @MrCkode if you want to return also #string write `'%#%s%'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field  RLIKE '#^[0-9]'
```

Comment: This is solution,thanks... Just I still need to limit to be at least three characters long...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  field LIKE '%#[0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```